# Single word for (request, response) pair? (casual words ok)

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I'm looking for an unambiguous word (or expression) for referring to a question and a corresponding answer as a single entity.

The word should express that no more and no less than 1 question and 1 answer is covered, and that they correspond to each other.

The terms "request, response" may be technical jargon but I'm looking for a general word (it may be technical or not).

(In case this should be obvious, please merge this to ELL, I'm not native.)

Comment: Do you mean in the sense of data? If so there are some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039513/what-is-a-request-response-pair-called

Comment: We need NameMyVariable.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user814064 this really helps when programming

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes". This is confirmed by OP's tag & comment.

Comment: In ling biz, this is called [Turn-taking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn-Taking), and Harvey Sacks provided a fine-grained analysis of how and why it works the way it does.

Comment: @TrevorD but I do not intend to name any variables. The programming-related usage is (intendedly unambiguous) talking. :)

Comment: I ended up calling a Request-Response Handler "ConnectionHandler" the other day, so "Connection"?

Answer (score 8):

*Exchange* or *interchange* might work in the absence of better words.

Comment: _Exchange_ is good but does not imply a question, consider this exchange: _- Hi. - Hi yourself._ Neither of these implies a short interchange though, both could describe conversations that lasted for hours.

Comment: Inquisitive Exchange?

Comment: conversation seems good, but is long and too far from computing

Answer (score 6):

Just call it a *Transaction* if you're not working with databases otherwise it can get confusing. I can also suggest *Discourse* but it may be a little far fetched.

I also want to add *handshake* as in a [WebSocket Protocol Handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_protocol_handshake)

Answer (score 3):

Well, how about [*Q&A*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/q+and+a)?

> Q and A 
>   noun Informal.
>   an exchange of questions and answers.
>   Also, Q&A.

If you are looking for variable names, you could always write `QnA` or `QA` or `QandA` or something.

Comment: I'm thinking that these call-and-response pairs should count as *antiphonal sequences* — or perhaps simply *ἀντίφωνα*. :)

Answer (score 3):

The compound word (or phrase if you omit the hyphens) *[call-and-response](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/call-and-response)* may suit

> a statement quickly followed by an answering statement; also : a musical phrase in which the first and often solo part is answered by a second and often ensemble part

Answer (score 1):

To me, the word "query" does contain the assumption that you expect a response to a request. Somebody (or something) who makes a query is an "enquirer".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word "Event" for referring to the entity... And this entity involves (or consists of) one Query and one Answer (Q&A).